# Clear IE10 AppCache Security request

Tags: security, internet-explorer, internet-security, web-application, offline-files

Unsure if this is more suited in StackOverflow. ??

My website is using the AppCache API. When IE users open it the first time a confirmation box pops up saying something like: "Allow this website to store information in the cache" with options to "Allow" or "Never for this domain".

Some of the users don't read and just (out of habit) click "Never for this domain" (or the cross), which breaks the site's functionality. When they realise what they've done they try to refresh the page, but the popup doesn't display again.

How can I (or they) clear their chosen setting? `Tools > Internet Options > General tab, Browsing History Settings > Caches & Databases tab` lists the allowed sites, but not the denied.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked in the end was in IE to open `Tools > Internet Options > General tab, Browsing History Settings > Caches & Databases tab` then disable the feature completely. Save everything and then enable the feature again.